# Parse a string and extract a word delimited by comma and assign value from inside [] brackets

Tags: shell, sed, scripting, cut

I need help to parse a string and extract a word delimited by comma and assign value from inside [] brackets.
The input string is like this:

```
KEEP_DFB,?(y/n),[y];
DFB_VERSION,?(1.4.2/1.7.6),[1.4.2]:
```

and expected output is

```
KEEP_DFB=y
DFB_VERSION=1.4.2
```

The closest I could achieve using sed is this:

```
echo 'KEEP_DFB,?(y/n),[y]:' | sed 's/\([^,]*,\).*,\([^,]*\):.*/\1=\2/'
```

but it does not give result as expected.

I also tried 'cut' but the same result as above.
Using IFS is not allowed for changing delimiter.
Can you please help?

Comment: does the pattern `(y/n),[y]` always hold true? I mean even in `(1.4.2/1.7.6),[1.4.2]` the value inside `[]` is same as value before `/` inside `()`

Comment: @Sundeep: since the question asks about capturing the value between the square brackets, it would be unwise to rely on the coincidence in the sample data that the same part of the material between round brackets matches the material between the square brackets.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah I think so to, I had not read the question fully, had prepared an answer and then noticed my assumption before posting... hence I asked the clarification as solution would be simpler..

Comment: When you are using this for asking values from the user, you might consider a different approach: make a `function askvalue` with parameters `question options defaultvalue` and use it as `KEEP_DFB=$(askvalue "Do you want to keep DFB" "y/n" "y")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your were fairly close:

```
$ printf "%s\n" 'DFB_VERSION,?(1.4.2/1.7.6),[1.4.2]:' 'KEEP_DFB,?(y/n),[y]:' |
> sed 's/\([^,]*\),.*,\[\([^],]*\)][;:].*/\1=\2/'
DFB_VERSION=1.4.2
KEEP_DFB=y
$
```

The first comma is moved outside the capture.  The second capture is preceded by `\[` (a literal `[` in the data) and followed by a `]` (doesn't need a backslash escape because `]` is only special when it is part of a character class, though I'd be sorely tempted to add one and it works fine with or without the backslash).

[Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep) noted that there's a semicolon instead of a colon in one of the data lines, but the example data in the `echo` has a colon rather than a semicolon (which is why I didn't spot the problem on the first pass; I copied the prototype command). That's trivially handled by using `[;:]` as a character class instead of a direct `:`.

The negated character class excludes `]` and commas — though it isn't clear why commas need to be excluded.  It means you wouldn't recognize this as valid:

```
VERSION_LIST,?(1.2/1.3/1.4/1.7),[1.4,1.7]:
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonathan.. this works fine and matches to the requirement script.. this is exactly what I was missing.. thank you so much for explanation.

Comment: Sorry I missed to note the last point... Yes, You guessed it right, this would be treated as invalid.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
sed 's/,.*\[/=/;s/].//' file
```

Output:

```
KEEP_DFB=y
DFB_VERSION=1.4.2
```

Comment: thank you @Cyrus though it works for the given set of example but also, I have to separate out the words at times and store it as in \1 \2 \3.. Jonathan has just answered me to the point.. and It helps me to understand my missing point in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX shell method, given input file '*foo*':

```
while IFS=',[]' read a b c d e ; do echo "$a${a:+=}$d" ; done < foo
```

Output:

```
KEEP_DFB=y
DFB_VERSION=1.4.2
```

Comment: What's the advantage of `${a:+=}` over `=` here? Is it to not print anything at all for empty lines? If so, a little explanation would help.

Comment: @BenjaminW., that's correct, without the `${a:+=}` the output would have useless `=` signs whenever a line was blank.   It's slightly faster than doing:  `[ "$a"] && echo "$a$=$d"`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code. It should work fine.

```
awk -F"," '{print $1,$3}' OFS="=" file_name | sed -e 's/\[\(.*\)\]./\1/'
```

This will output the line contained in a file using awk and replacing the delimiter by `=` and then replace the part starting from `[` and ending by `]` or any other character by the values inside `[]`.

You could also try this shorter one:

```
sed -e 's/,.*\[\(.*\)\]./=\1/' file
```

The output for both is:

```
KEEP_DFB=y
DFB_VERSION=1.4.2
```

Comment: or use `,` and `[` and `]` as delimiter: `awk -F'[,[\]]' '{print $1"="$4}' file`

Comment: @VinnyAdjibi: There is no need to use 1 awk and then 1 sed, you could wrap it up within 1 single awk(apart from what Cyrus has suggested).
awk -F"," '{gsub(/\[|\]|;|:/,X,$3);print $1,$3}' OFS="="  Input_file

Comment: @RavinderSingh : Thanks for the advice. I didn't know about gsub. Of course it is a shorter and faster way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[][,]' '{print $1"="$4}' file 

KEEP_DFB=y
DFB_VERSION=1.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what shell you are going to use, but with most shells, the following approach would work:

```
# Drop the last two characters
x=${original:0:-2}
# Store the name part
name=${x%%,*}
# Store the value part
value=${x##*\[}
```

For example, if `original` contains `DFB_VERSION,?(1.4.2/1.7.6),[1.4.2]:`, `name` will contain `DFB_VERSION` and `value` will contain `1.4.2`.

BTW, why don't you want to modify `IFS`? Of course you don't want to change it permanently, but modifying it just for one statement, does not affect the rest of the program.

Comment: It seems the script has to run on different build server, users may not be having 'root/superuser' permission or IFS may be disabled. So, an existing solution with IFS worked for 'root' users while it gets stuck for others.

Comment: You do not need to have superuser permission to change IFS, and I don't see a way where modification of IFS could be "disabled".

Answer (score 0):

@Suresh K: Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F, '{match($0,/\[.*\]/);print $1"="substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' Input_file
```

I hope this helps.